# how to get single row data in table php

Tags: php, html, css, printing

[image]
This is the main table which shows all the data from database, when I click the print it should only print the that row but it does not show up I get "Undefined variable: row" and im starting to think this has to do with this here the code for the table:

```
 <div class="container" >
        <div class="well" ">
            <span class="pull-right"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Enroll Pupil</a></span>
            <div>
</div>
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" >
                    <thead>
                        <th >Moble Number</th>
                        <th >First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Section</th>
                        <th>Grade</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        include('conn.php');

                        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `tbl_students`");
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                        ?>

                        <tr s>
                            <td><?php echo $row['LRN']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['FirstName']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['LastName']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['Section']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['GradeLevel']; ?></td>
                            
                            <td >
                                <a href="#editstudent<?php echo $row['LRN']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a> | | 
                                <a href="#delstudent<?php echo $row['LRN']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete</a> | |
                                <a href="#addmoto<?php echo $row['LRN']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addmoto" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Add Subject</a> | |
                                <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.open('IndivPrintTableStudent.php').print();">Print</a>
                            <?php include('buttonstudent.php'); ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }

                    ?>
                </tbody>
```

[image: Here is my Database] here is my database

```
 <?php include"includes/config.php" ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Print.css" media="print"></link>
     <div class="container" >

<table>
                  <thead>
                        <th style="border: 3px solid #2F323A; text-align: center; padding-bottom: 8px;">Moble Number</th>
                        <th style="border: 3px solid #2F323A; text-align: center; width: 14%;">First Name</th>
                        <th style="border: 3px solid #2F323A; text-align: center; width: 14%;">Last Name</th>
                        <th style="border: 3px solid #2F323A; text-align: center; padding-bottom: 9px;">Section</th>
                        <th style="border: 3px solid #2F323A; text-align: center; width: 10%;">Grade</th>
                        
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                       
                <?php
                    $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_students WHERE LRN='".$row['LRN']."'");
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                             ?>
                
                        <tr style="background-color: #f0f8ff; border: 3px solid #2F323A;">
                            <td style="border: 3px solid #2F323A; padding-top: 15px; color: #2F323A;"><?php echo $row['LRN']; ?></td>
                            <td style="border: 3px solid #2F323A; padding-top: 15px; color: #2F323A;"><?php echo $row['FirstName']; ?></td>
                            <td style="border: 3px solid #2F323A; padding-top: 15px; color: #2F323A;"><?php echo $row['LastName']; ?></td>
                            <td style="border: 3px solid #2F323A; padding-top: 15px; color: #2F323A;"><?php echo $row['Section']; ?></td>
                            <td style="border: 3px solid #2F323A; padding-top: 15px; color: #2F323A;"><?php echo $row['GradeLevel']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        } 
                              ?>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                         
                         
                    </div>
```

how do I get single data in individual manner? the error that I get s "Undefined variable: row" which you can see on the query. i dont know why it says that I only made this is table form just to see if i can get the actual data from a single student. I hope my question can be understandable.

Comment: i can see from your code that the variable $row is defined

Comment: can I see your database table?

Comment: crap I forgot to mention that this code is the output of printing.

Comment: @NazmulHossainPappu yes, I'll edit my post.

Comment: If the SQL returns a single row then the code will output a single row. You wouldn't need to change anything in the PHP. It just depends on the result of the query. It shouldn't be possible for this code to produce the error you're claiming though.

Comment: I'll try to edit my post again because I think it has to do with my main table which shows all the data.

Comment: I see. Your button is linking to `IndivPrintTableStudent.php` but you aren't passing the ID of the clicked row in the URL, so probably that script doesn't know which row you wanted to display. I'm guessing maybe it expects the row ID as a GET parameter maybe? Hard to be sure as we can't see that bit of code

Comment: bro, upload your full code into GitHub or googledrive include the database, then share it. I think I found the solution before I give you the solutions I need to try, thanks!

Comment: Also `$row['LRN']` in the second script isn't going to exist because it's part of a different script, variables are not carried across automatically from one script to another. You have to pass them in the URL

Comment: i sort of get it what you mean. how do I do that?

Comment: ok. Ill upload it on github @NazmulHossainPappu

Comment: @NazmulHossainPappu no, that's not how this site is supposed to work. Any relevant information needs to be **here** in the question page. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic especially the numbered item 1

Comment: @ADyson alright.

Comment: You'd have something like `onclick="window.open('IndivPrintTableStudent.php?LRN=<?PHP echo $row["LRN"]; ?>').print();` in the first table. And then the second script would use `$_GET["LRN"]` to retrieve that value from the URL and use it in the sql query. (beware of SQL injection though, learn how to use parameters and prepared statements to protect your database)

Comment: oh so I cant send it :(. @ADyson so do I have just to <?php echo $row['LRN"]?>? inside the anchor tag?

Comment: Huh? My example shows you how to send it

Comment: @ADyson Thank you it finally worked. yes If I have time I would study about security. how do I mark your answer to also show people who might have the same problem?

Comment: @ADyson im sorry if im replying late i was working on it.

Comment: Glad it worked. I will add it below as a proper answer then you can accept it, hang on a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is linking to IndivPrintTableStudent.php but you aren't passing the ID of the clicked row in the URL, so that script doesn't know which row you wanted to display. `$row['LRN']` in the second script isn't going to exist because it's part of a different script, variables are not carried across automatically from one script to another. You have to pass them in the URL.

You'd have something like

`onclick="window.open('IndivPrintTableStudent.php?LRN=<?php echo $row["LRN"]; ?>').print();`

in the print button on the first table.

And then the second script would use `$_GET["LRN"]` to retrieve that value from the URL and use it in the sql query.

(Beware of SQL injection though, learn how to use parameters and prepared statements to protect your database - see https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli for examples.)